# Disable Adaptive Sampling in Azure Application Insights

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, azure-application-insights

I am working with an Asp.Net core application. I have the configuration to disable adaptive sampling of Application Insights in appsettings.json file, as below,

```
"ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "EnableAdaptiveSampling": false
  }
```

And in the Startup.cs, I register the dependency of Application Insights using,

```
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
```

My understanding is that, with these changes in place, the above mentioned section from appsettings.json configures the instrumentation key and disables adaptive sampling.

Is my understanding correct or is it mandatory to apply these configurations in Startup.cs using ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions to actually disable adaptive sampling in Application Insights telemetry?

Also, with Azure Functions, I have the following configuration in place,

```
"logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "Application_Name": "Information"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": false
      }
    }
  }
```

I came through many blogs, that says, these host.json settings are enough for Azure Functions to disable adaptive sampling.

Is this correct?

Comment: The appsettings.json is correct (it takes instrumentationkey, and disables sampling), as long as you are in 2.15 or newer of the SDK. see official doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core#configuration-recommendation-for-microsoftapplicationinsightsaspnetcore-sdk-2150-and-later

Comment: @cijothomas So, services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(aiOptions) this one is used to override what we have in appsettings.json?

Comment: Any updates about this question? Did this answer resolve your issue?